# No entra la bucle for

Tags: java, bucle-for, netbeans-8.2

resulta que no entra en el bucle y no entiendo porqué. Estoy seguro de que la manera en lograr mi objetivo no es la más adecuada, fácil ni lógica, pero es lo que se me ocurrió para hacer una prueba jajaja.

La idea es utilizar un método que le pase como parámetro de entrada un número y un vector y busque ese número en el vector y lo devuelva. 
Para ello creo un bucle para que busque cual es el último valor que esté en el vector (para distinguirlo y no ponerle la coma al final al imprimirlo por pantalla, es una chorrada pero quería probarlo). Luego creo otro bucle que me rellene un String con los las posiciones donde coincidan los valores y finalmente imprimirlo todo por pantalla.

El error se produce en el bucle for siguiente: "for(int j=a;j==0;j--){". Nunca se imprime el mensaje de "por aquí entro", ya que no entra jajaja. Creo que el problema está en la condición y/o la actualización pero mi razonamiento me da a pensar que está bien. Muchas gracias!; el código de la clase lo dejo por aquí:

```
package prueba1;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ejercicios {

    public static void buscar(int x, ArrayList<Integer> elementos){
        String lecturaPosiciones ="";
        int ultimaPos =-1;
        int a =(elementos.size()-1);
        System.out.println(a);

        for(int j=a;j==0;j--){
            System.out.println("por aquí entro");
            if(elementos.get(j) == x){
                ultimaPos = (elementos.size()-j-1);
                break;
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i< elementos.size();i++){
            if(elementos.get(i)==x){
                lecturaPosiciones += String.valueOf(i);
                if(i!= ultimaPos){
                    lecturaPosiciones +=", ";
                }else{
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if( ultimaPos ==(-1)){
            System.out.println("El valor de "+x+" no está dentro del vector");
        }else{
            System.out.println("El valor de "+x+" se encuentra en las "
                    + "posiciones: "+lecturaPosiciones+", "
                    + "donde las posiciones van desde 0 hasta el número de elementos -1");
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> listado = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            listado.add(i);
        }
        System.out.println(listado.size());
        buscar(4, listado);


    }
}
```

La respuesta es:

run:

10

9

El valor de 4 no está dentro del vector

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: Es un error tipográfico: `for(int j=a;j==0;j--){` debería ser `for(int j = a; j >= 0; j--) {`

Answer (score 2):

Cambia

```
 for(int j=a;j==0;j--)
```

por

```
for(int j=a;j>=0;j--)
```

Se entra en el for solo si se cumple la condición central, por tanto, si metías algo que fuese distinto de cero, no entra en el for.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, no sabía eso último que comentabas para que pueda entrar al bucle for.
Un saludo!